# My react-native is reading directly from the git master url instead of an npm version

Tags: reactjs, react-native, github, npm

My `react-native` in my `package.json` is reading directly from the git master url instead of an npm version and this is causing the error of my React Native project when executing `:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac.` every time I run `npm run-android`. I want to safely change the react-native of an npm version. How can I do that?

This is my react-native:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can change your version to one of the latest versions like 0.57, then run the command "npm install".

```
"react-native": "0.57.0"
```

You may have to run the command "react-native link" too.

Comment: Should I do that in cmd or just in my terminal?

Comment: You may use node.js command prompt or terminal, you should be in your project folder in command line.

Comment: When I enter `react-native link` it does nothing?

Comment: Can you give more detail about your environment?